# how to make a function execute only if there was a change in two input fields

Tags: javascript, forms, class, object

I am working on a note taking web application and I have attached an eventListener to two input fields that when executed ,runs a method ,but the problem is that this method runs whenever there was a change in any of the input fields and ends up executing this method twice

```
  [inputBody, inputTitle].forEach((inputField) => {
        inputField.addEventListener("change", () => {
          const newTitle = inputTitle.value.trim();
          const newBody = inputBody.value.trim();
          const saveEditedNote = this.root.querySelector(".save-btn");
          saveEditedNote.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const editedNote = {
              id: noteItem.dataset.noteId,
              title: newTitle,
              body: newBody,
            };
            this.onNoteEdit(editedNote);
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: that can be solved with a test variable, false at beginning, true if change on 1, test variable if change on each, if true execute and reset. If you don't want a global variable, put a data-change="false" in each. When change one, change to true, test the other one, if both true excecute your code and reset both to false

Comment: Just delegate.  NEVER add an event listener in an event listener. Use `e.target.closest('someCommonContainer').querySelector(inputFieldSelector).value` to get at the input fields in the click handler